# Debian 10: `startx` on console terminal via ssh produces error

Tags: debian, ssh, lightdm

As I understand it a "console terminal/user" is a user logged into a "console terminal" (CTRL+ALT+ {F1 to F7})

Heres a sequence of what I've done

- Boot local machine
- Login on login screen (console F7)
- Change to console F1
- Login (local, again)
- `ssh -Y user@server`
- `startx`

This error is produced

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
```

I have lightdm installed. This is the output of `systemd status`

```
sudo systemctl status lightdm

● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-06-26 16:00:33 BST; 22h ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
 Main PID: 3565 (lightdm)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 22.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
           ├─3565 /usr/sbin/lightdm
           ├─3577 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
           └─3639 lightdm --session-child 14 21

Jun 26 16:00:33 server systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Jun 26 16:00:33 server systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Jun 26 16:00:33 server lightdm[3565]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: T
Jun 26 16:00:34 server lightdm[3594]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: T
Jun 26 16:00:34 server lightdm[3594]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
```

I do not know if those error lines are related to the problem I am observing.

The suggested linked question does not solve the problem.

The linked question **seems to be** in relation to root privilages and starting `startx`.

I checked my `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and it already contains `allowed_users=console`.

This is one of the suggested possible answers to that question.

There is a third "answer" which is **related to sessions over ssh whereas the origional question is not related to this and neither are the two other answers** however this does not solve the problem, because it is another question, not an answer. It appears to me that this user might have had the same issue I am having, however it is not clear to me because minimal details are given.

Comment: It is surprising that _Why am I not a "console user" to Xorg when I have logged in to the machine via SSH?_ does not already have a Q&A here.

Comment: @user3728501 the language in the revisions to this questions is stronger than it needs to be. The community here are all volunteers, and among them are people who might answer your question. Please stick with the facts and avoid aspersions. In short: [be nice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: [Can't run `startx` from inside screen session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328058/80216) contains part of the answer,  but it’s not presented clearly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `startx` on an ssh connection, you use X forwarding. After connecting using `ssh -Y` or `ssh -X` you can start an X application which will draw its windows on your local pc, using your local X server. Try to execute `xclock &` or `firefox &` or whatever GUI app you need to be executed on the remote machine, but display its windows locally.

Check for this line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:
`X11Forwarding yes`

In modern systems with X forwarding enabled you don't need `DISPLAY` variable to be set; if you face any issues, `export DISPLAY=[your local display, for example :0]`

Actually you can even start X apps locally without X running on remote machine at all, since your local X server is used.

`Xpra` is interesting also, especially on slower connections. It's a more sophisticated way to forward X apps.

If you need full remote desktop access, you should use something like `VNC`, `X2Go`, `xrdp` etc.

Comment: So the answer is simple "this cannot be done". There's no way to use the x window system like a remote desktop? (At least in the modern setting.) I guess my confusion came from reading about the history of linux/unix and how multiple terminals used to log into some much larger computing system, like a central server or mainframe. Presumably, then, those users did not at any point have access to an x window system?

Comment: Of course it can be used as a remote desktop. My last line, is about remote desktop, `VNC`, `X2Go`. There is also another solution which I forgot, `xrdp`. After instaling and running `xrdp` on your Linux server, you can use rdp protocol to connect, just like a Windows machine. That is, `mstsc.exe` standard rdp client for Windows clients or `xfreerdp` on UNIX or Linux.

Comment: But it can't be used as a remote desktop using the x-server, without installing a remote desktop server. This is the question I am asking.